# Hyperref not appearing in headings

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing

When I enable hyperref, any cross referencing used in headings gets replaced with "??". When I disable hyperref, everything works as expected. Here's a MWE and a screenshot of the issue. I'm fairly certain I didn't have this problem until a few days ago, unless I just never noticed...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter{Hello \ref{Link}}
\section{Test}\label{Link}
lorem
\newpage
ipsum
\newpage
snoopy
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of issue]

Instead of "Hello ??", it should say "Hello Test". Any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1203) (last answer by @Stephan Kottwitz), the problem arises from uppercase conversion. You then should use uppercase labels.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \chapter{Hello \ref{LINK}}
    \section{Test}\label{LINK}
    lorem
    \newpage
    ipsum
    \newpage
    snoopy
\end{document}
```